# Tagging GDN and Video Ads UT Override for non 360 customers

Tags: google-ads, utm-parameters, google-ads-valuetrack

I would like to auto tag my Ad Search campaigns but would like my Video and GDN campaigns to have a medium of 'Display' as opposed to CPM. I know you can do a UTM override if you are a 360 customer. Is there any way to do this if you aren't?